# How do I output the results of a single MS SQL select statement as a single line

Tags: sql-server

I created the following select statement:

```
SELECT     x.Code, y.AttributeCode, y.Value
FROM         x INNER JOIN
                      y ON x.Id = y.ItemCodeId
WHERE  (AttributeCode = 'Length' or AttributeCode = 'Width' or AttributeCode = 'Height')
```

The results display like this:

```
Code    AttributeCode   Value
1000165 Width              4
1000165 Length           19.5
1000165 Height            3.8
1000173 Length             3
1000173 Height             8
1000173 Width              5
```

And I'd like them to display as follows:

```
100165 Width 4 Length 19.5 Height 3.8
100173 Width 5 Length 3    Height 8
```

I apologize if this is a repeat but I looked through several other answers to try to answer this question (MS SQL is new to me so I may just not be using the right language when I'm searchign).

Comment: +1 for a well asked question that is clear and provides all of the necessary information (and some effort yourself to find a solution first before posting).

Answer (score 3):

Tsk, tsk, someone is going [EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model). Anyway, [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) can be used in this case to shred a finite set of values back into columns. It's an SQL Server extension to standard SQL - but it's a very useful extension for such cases:

> PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dab02/1) showing PIVOT:

```
-- SETUP
create table x (entity int, attribute varchar(20), value float);
insert into x (entity, attribute, value) values 
  (1000165, 'Width', 4),
  (1000165, 'Length', 19.5),
  (1000165, 'Height', 3.8),
  (1000173, 'Length', 3),
  (1000173, 'Height', 8),
  (1000173, 'Width', 5)

-- QUERY
SELECT pvt.*
FROM (SELECT entity, attribute, value FROM x) AS src
PIVOT (
  -- Have to use an aggregate, but we have multiplicity of one as
  -- presented so that's not an issue: MAX of any single value is itself.
  -- Note that there is an implicit GROUP BY on columns NOT in
  -- the aggregate ([value]) or used for the pivot ([attribute]) which
  -- leaves only [entity] as the grouping column.
  MAX(value)
  FOR attribute IN ([Width], [Length], [Height])
  ) AS pvt

-- RESULT
ENTITY      WIDTH   LENGTH  HEIGHT
1000165     4       19.5    3.8
1000173     5       3       8
```

The input to PIVOT (`src`) and the result from PIVOT can be filtered or joined as needed. The only real "gotcha" to watch out for with PIVOT is accidentally carrying over an extra (and incorrectly anticipated) grouping column

Comment: +1 for the ticking off about the use of entity-attribute-value model

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Code, a.AttributeCode, a.Value, b.AttributeCode, b.Value, c.AttributeCode, c.Value
FROM x
INNER JOIN y a ON x.Id = a.ItemCodeId
INNER JOIN y b ON x.Id = b.ItemCodeId
INNER JOIN y c ON x.Id = c.ItemCodeId
WHERE (a.AttributeCode = 'Width') and (b.AttributeCode = 'Length') and (c.AttributeCode = 'Height')
```